# How to remove an emulsion paint off a cat's leg?

Tags: cats

I just found that a pregnant cat got an emuslion paint on its leg, it is a street cat that stays around my house and sometimes I let it in, also, I feed it and pet it. I saw her shaking her leg, maybe because she is annoyed of the paint and want to remove it. So, how to remove that paint?

Answer (score 2):

There is several ways to remove toxic substances from a pets fur.

You can use food oil to soften the paint and use a pet safe shampoo and water to remove this.

A better way is to shave off the fur on the affected area but you need to let a vet do this as a cat's skin is so loose you might hurt the cat and end up at the vet anyway.

If the paint is water based you can remove it with lukewarm water and gently rub the area if the paint is fresh.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest concern seems to be preventing paint ingestion from the cat trying to clean itself.
If I understand it correctly, emulsion paint is water based which means a kitty bath might solve the problem. Dawn dish detergent has always been animal friendly... they used it to clean up Pelicans after the Valdez Oil Spill, so I imagine it would work for water based paint. This [wikiHow page has more information](https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Paint-from-a-Cat%27s-Fur)  about potential options.